# CSS Media Queries not activating at specified widths. Why not?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a bar that spans across the page (100% width) with a child container inside of it that spans 80% of the parent container's width.

I have the following CSS media query that is supposed to increase the child container's width from 80% to 100%:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px), screen and (max-device-width: 900px){
    #imagebar .container{
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

However, using the dimensions given to me by my chrome developer tools, the query is taking affect at a width of 990px. Not 900px. This is occurring with all my media queries; they are all activating 80-100px earlier than they should be. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: I just created a demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EkIlt, which is working fine. Are you referring dimensions displayed on top right corner?

Comment: @Tushar fiddle is working fine. I think you have one more media query definition bottom of this, and that is overwriting this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is formatted wrong.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px), screen and (max-device-width: 900px){
    #imagebar{
        .container{
            width: 100%; 
        }
    }
}
```

should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px), screen and (max-device-width: 900px){
#imagebar .container{
        width: 100%; }
```

If you want to call on an element inside another element, dont open both elements, just specify which element in which parent you want to edit or change.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to specify that I was using sass. Let me edit the post.

Comment: "This is formatted wrong." Yeah, you probably meant to format it as a proper code block rather than using backticks...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this it will work for  you

```
/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  your css  here 

}
```